# Dreamhost subversion post-commit hooks not working

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, cgi, dreamhost

I have looked at many many articles online but none have seemed to yield an answer.
I run a setup where:

I have a website that will run a copy of trunk files
This website has an svn folder associated with it
I have a local testing environment of wampserver/mamp on my mac, tortoise svn on my pc

So i have a checkout of the repository, i make my changes and when I have a release - I commit the files.

I would like an automatic update on commit to the svn repository - this wiki explains how to do it: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Subversion#Automatic_Post-commit_Checkout

unfortunately it is fraught with problems. Once i had my cgi folders and my updated post-commit hook sortedm i was recieving the exit code of 255. After i converted the cgi and the hook to unix and re-uploaded i had an exit code of 1.

I changed the chmod again, and no i recieve no errors.
And unfortunately dreamhost does not update the files into my live site.

My hook file looks like this:

post commit:

```
        #!/bin/bash
        wget --http-user=username --http-passwd=password -qO - http://website.com/cgi-bin/pri/do_update.cgi
```

and my do_update.cgi:
        #!/bin/sh

```
    # disable filename globbing
    set -f

    echo "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1"
    echo

    echo /usr/bin/svn update /home/username/website.com
```

Google returns many many pages with this problem, and unless i suddenly learn how to compile a program in C, i wont be able to make this work.

Any help appreciated, and would finally put a good answer out on the internet for everyone else...

Answer (score 1):

after much trouble like yourself, **i have finally gotten svn post-commit hook working on Dreamhost**.  Both of my files are identical to yours, except it looks like you've got an extra 'echo' in your cgi script.

The permissions on my cgi file are: *-rwxr-xr-x* (that's 755 if i remember correctly)

Don't forget about the .htaccess/.htpasswd setup for your /cgi-bin/ directory:

Here's what my .htaccess in the /cgi-bin/ directory looks like:

```
AuthName "Dialog prompt"

AuthType Basic

AuthUserFile /home/username/x.com/cgi-bin/.htpasswd

Require valid-user
```

Keep in mind, the username/password for your 'wget' in the cgi-script file is NOT your svn user/pass, but the user/pass you setup for the cgi-bin directory specifically through that .htaccess file (also NOT your DH username/pass).  I'm not sure where the svn user/pass comes into play, perhaps only on the initial checkout (through bash).

I was researching SO last night to find out how to 'reset' my SVN (it stopped running the post-commit hook, but didn't report any errors).  For fixing *this* issue, I had to log-in to DH via bash, then manually run an `svn up`.  Upon running that command in my X.com site directory, SVN finally reported back an error (a 'file already existed', and svn wasn't overwriting it).  To remedy this, i simply re-did my update command to:  `svn up --force`.  Whammy!, my svn ran a full update in my web directory and finally i had my latest files ON my webserver.  Whew!

If i recall correctly (having had this post-commit-hook working properly for months), i had to INITIALLY do an `svn checkout` into my web directory via bash.  Once that initial checkout was done, the hook's `svn update` worked properly.  (FYI, i use tortoise for all my usual commits)

Good luck to everyone trying to run post-commit-hooks on DH. It may be hard to setup, but in the end, totally worth it!

:-P

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do, it isn't on a linux machine, but it seems to work for me to just call svn directly on the post-commit.  If you have a large export it does delay your checkin a little bit, but is super simple. Should be very similar for linux machines.

The hook:

```
svn.exe export https://myhostname/svn/project/trunk %WEBSITEDIR%\httpdocs\store --quiet --non-interactive --force --username user --password pass
```